# Using the move command with /Y in a bat file

Tags: batch-file

I need to move all folders in a directory called Profile.V2 out of the directory and then I want to delete the directory. I'm using a bat file to do this which is below, this works perfectly except when a folder with the same name already exists in the location I am moving the files/folders to, this causes the bat file to stop and a prompt to appear asking if it is Ok to overwrite the folder. The move command has an argument /Y that surpress the prompt, however if I place it after "move" in my bat file it doesn't work. Can anyone spot why and where should it go?

```
@ECHO OFF
H:
cd Profile.V2
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b') do (
  move "%%a" H:\
)
RD /S /Q H:\Profile.V2
```

Many thanks
Steve

Comment: try: echo y|move "%%a" h:\

Answer (score 1):

Well. I would just do "move /Y *.* H:\"
As far as I can tell that does the same as the for loop.

The /Y goes immediately after move and **has to be** upper-case.

(Officially it isn't case sensitive, but I know from experience that somehow it does matter on some systems. I've never managed to find out why.)

Answer (score 0):

The Move command requires that the target directory **does not exist** and will fail if it does.  There are no command line arguments that can fix this.

You might consider this script instead:

```
@ECHO OFF
H:
xcopy h:\Profile.V2 h:\ /s/e/v/y
RD /S /Q H:\Profile.V2
```

Xcopy will copy the contents of directory Profile.V2 to the root of the H: drive, and to overwrite existing files without prompting. It will create all directories found in profile.v2, including empty ones.

Moving the contents might be a lesser goal, since your RD command removes the directory without verification.

For an explanation of the command line arguments, type:

```
xcopy /?
```